# s3 - auto compression before transfer

Tags: python, amazon-s3, compression

I want to know :

1. If any available tool by **default** compress and transfer file
   to S3
2. or tool has option to compress and transfer file to S3
3. or I have to call python libraries and compress and then transfer to S3

Comment: Do you want to store the _compressed_ version of the file in Amazon S3, or do you just want to compress it while being transferred but store the non-compressed file in S3?

Comment: purpose is : make file transfer to be fast . 
So compress before

Answer (score 1):

You can do with simple python code if you want to.

```
import gzip
import json
import boto3


# To compress
# Data to compress
data = [{'name': 'test'}, {'name': 'test2'}]
# Converting data to string
json_str = json.dumps(data) + "\n"
# Converting to bytes
json_bytes = json_str.encode('utf-8')
jsonfilename = "s3_compressed_file.json.gz"
# Compressing to gzip
with gzip.GzipFile(jsonfilename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_bytes)


# Upload to S3
s3BucketName = 'mybucket'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
# if you want to rename file while uploading
file_name = 's3_compressed_file-1.json.gz'
# '/current_dir_path/' + filename, '<bucket-name>', 's3_folder/{}'.format(filename)
s3_response = s3_resource.meta.client.upload_file('source_dir/' + 's3_compressed_file.gz', s3BucketName,
                                                      'destination_dir/{}'.format(file_name))
```